# How can different quantifiers make regex behave differently?

Tags: regex

Playing around with  [a question asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287438/whats-the-best-way-to-identify-redundant-word-sequences-in-a-text) (put on hold, but I wanted to fiddle with it ;) I stumbled across a peculiarity I'd like to ask this knowledgeable community about. Namely - **why do these two regexes give different results**?

```
(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)(?:.*?(\1))(?:.*?(\1))?(?:.*?(\1))?
```

vs.

```
(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)(?:.*?(\1)){1,3}
```

[First at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OzDdCs/3) - [Second at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OzDdCs/4)

What I wanted to do, was to have this regex:

```
(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)(?:.*?(\1))+
```

detect repeated word sequences - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OzDdCs/1). (a word followed by at least one more. Then anything up to a repetition of the identified sequence, then this last part possibly repeated any number of times. I.e. one or more repetitions.)

What it did was find a sequence that repeated it self later in the document, **but it skipped to the last one**. OK, though I consider me somewhat comfortable around regexes, I know greediness vs. lazy can be confusing. And I wanted it to catch *all* repetitions.

So I tried to force it by repeating the second part instead of using a quantifier:

```
(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)(?:.*?(\1))(?:.*?(\1))
```

and then it worked like expected - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OzDdCs/2).

That made me try the two regexes first mentioned, that in my opinion should yield the same result, but they don't. So, again - What makes them give different results?

Comment: `(?:.*?(\1))(?:.*?(\1))?(?:.*?(\1))?` -> you create 3 different capturing groups. `(?:.*?(\1)){1,3}` -> you create 1 capturing group, that is repeated, thus only the last occurence is stored. So they match exactly the same, only the storing of the groups is different.

Comment: @SebastianProske **How stupid am I**? Of course! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. (Or maybe I should delete it, because now that you've answered it, I realize it's a duplicate)

Comment: Feel free to delete it, i don't wanna go dupe hunting ;)

Comment: @SebastianProske Can't find an *exact* duplicate, so maybe I'll leave it here. So, again, post your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ClasG: note also that the Python regex module and .net regex engine support repeated capture groups and make available the list of captures.

Answer (score 1):

When you repeat a capture group, only the last "capture" is put in the back reference.

For example `/A(B)+/` used on the string "ABBB" would put the last "B" in capture group $1.

But `/A(B)(B)(B)/` has 3 capture groups and thus will have a "B" in $1 & $2 & $3

That's why in those 2 regex examples you showed, the first will also mark that 2nd "my cat is black".
But the second regex example won't.

Answer (score 1):

Your original pattern, `(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)(?:.*?(\1))+`, is going to skip to the last repeated sub-pattern because you are telling it to do that with that last `+` - you are *quantifying a capture group*, which means that `(?:.*?(\1))+` will *not* stop when it first hits "my cat is black", it'll keep repeating itself until the longest match is found, at which point all intermediate matches of the capture group are discarded.

Generally speaking, don't quantify capture groups, capture quantified groups.

I think what you want is simply this:

`(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)+).*?(\1)`

https://regex101.com/r/OzDdCs/7